# How to use index variable generated from v-for from prent tag in child-tag's v-for value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, v-for

```
  <tr v-for='(dialog, dialogIdx) in this.$store.state.dialogSearch.content_keys '>
          <td rowspan='11'>
              <router-link to='' tag='button' class='btn-round'> {{dialog}} d</router-link>
          </td>
          <tr v-for='(content, ContentIdx) in this.$store.state.dialogSearch.contents[dialogIdx]'>
          </tr>
  </tr>
```

I want take variable dialogIdx that is generated from parent tag's v-for and use the dialogIdx in child tag's v-for value.
I've tried

```
<tr v-for=`(content, ContentIdx) in this.$store.state.dialogSearch.contents[${dialogIdx}]`
```

```
<tr v-for="(content, ContentIdx) in this.$store.state.dialogSearch.contents[{{dialogIdx}}]"
```

[image]

Comment: could you hover over the curly error line and tell what error/warning it's showing you?

Comment: The message is Unresolved variable or type dialogIdx

Answer (score 1):

It's only because you used `this` keyword for the nested `v-for` directive. `this` refers to the function context that invoked the code execution, which in your case will be the parent `v-for` directive. Try removing the `this` keyword from the second `v-for` loop. You can map the `this.$store.state["dialogSearch/contents"]` to a computed property and then use it within the nested `v-for` loop without the `this` keyword.

###### Sample implementation

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      content_keys: {
        0: 'Label 1',
        1: 'Label 2',
        2: 'Label 3',
        3: 'Label 4',
      },
      child_keys: {
        0: {
          0: 'Label 1 Child 1',
          1: 'Label 1 Child 2',
          2: 'Label 1 Child 3',
          3: 'Label 1 Child 4'
        },
        1: {
          0: 'Label 2 Child 1',
          1: 'Label 2 Child 2',
          2: 'Label 2 Child 3',
          3: 'Label 2 Child 4'
        },
        2: {
          0: 'Label 3 Child 1',
          1: 'Label 3 Child 2',
          2: 'Label 3 Child 3',
          3: 'Label 3 Child 4'
        },
        3: {
          0: 'Label 4 Child 1',
          1: 'Label 4 Child 2',
          2: 'Label 4 Child 3',
          3: 'Label 4 Child 4'
        },
      },
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id=app>
  <table border="1">
    <tr v-for="(dialog, dialogIdx) in this.content_keys">
      <td>{{ dialog }}</td>
      <td v-for="(content, contentIdx) of child_keys[dialogIdx]">
        {{ dialogIdx }} : {{ content }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check an optimized unique approach using reusable computed property

```
computed: {
   getContent() {
       return contextObj => {
        if(contextObj.label ==='content_keys') return this.$store.state.dialogSearch.content_keys;
        else return this.$store.state.dialogSearch.contents[contextObj.key];
      }
    }
}
```

and the changes in your template should be

```
 <tr v-for="(dialog, dialogIdx) in getContent({label: 'content_keys})">
          <td rowspan='11'>
              <router-link to='' tag='button' class='btn-round'> {{dialog}} d</router-link>
          </td>
          <tr v-for="(content, ContentIdx) in getContent({label: 'content_index', key: dialogIdx})">
          </tr>
  </tr>
```